# Javascript Show Hide on click

Tags: javascript, hide, show, show-hide

Show a new div on click

```
<div id="box1">abc</div>
<div id="box2" style="display:none;">awklnnbc</div>
<div id="box3" style="display:none;">wgweilwe</div>
<div id="box4" style="display:none;">vwfweifu</div>
<div id="box5" style="display:none;">xvwervwe</div>
<div id="box6" style="display:none;">gwevw</div>


<button>Show Another Div</button>
```

after clicking on show another div

```
<div id="box1">abc</div>
<div id="box2" style="display:none;">awklnnbc</div>
<div id="box3" style="display:none;">wgweilwe</div>
<div id="box4" style="display:none;">vwfweifu</div>
<div id="box5" style="display:none;">xvwervwe</div>
<div id="box6" style="display:none;">gwevw</div>


<button>Show Another Div</button>
```

a new div will be appearing on every click.

hope you understand now.

Only box1 will be visible first. rest of them hidden. different content on different div.
If you someone click on show another div, a new div will be showing.
is it possible?

Comment: It is possible. what have you tried?

Comment: Lots of effort in your post. You have not even specified the preferred sequence. That is, should it be a random new div that is shown? Can divs previously shown be shown again, etc. And yes, it's possible.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers sorry i am really bad at javascript. that's why i am asking. :(

Answer (score 1):

This has a good answer for your problem I believe: http://csscreator.com/node/708

Answer (score 0):

If you want do dynamically add a new div you should just try appending it to the content:

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <button id="showNewDiv">SHOW ANOTHER DIV</button>
</div>
```

The Javascript (assuming you are using jQuery)

```
$("#showNewDiv").on("click", function(e){
   $("#content").append("<div/>", {text: "whatever"});
});
```